# jenkins pipeline tfs_changeset not working

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Using Jenkins pipeline job, I am trying to print the `TFS_CHANGESET` but all I get is `null`. Can someone check the code below?

```groovy
import hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamFoundationServerScm
node {
  serverUrl = "http://SERVERNAME:8080/tfs/ORG"
  projectPath = "\$/DigitalPlatforms/Syndication/Dev"
    try {
        deleteDir()
        stage 'download-from-scm'
        def workspace = pwd() + '/' + "Hudson-testingtfs-MASTER"
        ws("/var/lib/jenkins/testing/testingtfs" + '/' + "Hudson-testingtfs-MASTER") {
        def out = checkout changelog: false, poll: false, scm: [$class: 'TeamFoundationServerScm', credentialsConfigurer: [$class: 'AutomaticCredentialsConfigurer'], projectPath: "${projectPath}", serverUrl: "${serverUrl}", useOverwrite: true, useUpdate: true, workspaceName: 'Hudson-${JOB_NAME}-${NODE_NAME}']

echo "${workspace}/${env.TFS_CHANGESET}"  //null for TFS_CHANGESET
echo "${env.TFS_CHANGESET}"  //null
}
        } catch (err) {
             currentBuild.result = 'FAILED'
             throw err
             }
}
```

if I try with a job (not pipeline) and then upon build, execute shell and check for `TFS_CHANGESET`, I get the correct value.

jenkins version: 2.75
pipeline plugin:1.5.3.1
Team Foundation Server Plug-in: 5.126.0

Comment: issue resolved after "Pipeline SCM Step" plugin updated to 2.6 (was 2.5), note that TFS_CHANGESET is available as map value of variable "out" above so you need to parse it out.